# Calculating the median across a range of categories in columns - Excel

Tags: excel, median

So in our experiment we took several samples from a number of fields. In each of these areas we counted the number of clover plants and their sizes. So each row of the table is one sample with how many size1, size2 (etc) plants appeared in that sample. So I want to know whether there is a code that I can put into column G that will work out what the median size class is.

For example, Column G would show 'size1' for Row 7, because it is the middle value if the data were lined up (size1, size1, size1, size2,size4).

[image: Our data]

Again I'm sorry if I'm making a total pig's ear of this. Stats seems to be very good at stumping me at the simplest things.

Comment: What makes it the `median`, just the fact there's a non-`0` number? So for row 2, you want to return `size3`, for row 7, want to return `size2`?

Comment: Are these frequencies and could more than one column be filled in for a particular row? I may be over-thinking this, but in that case you could get a median like 2.5 and it could be one of two sizes.

Comment: So if a row had `1, 0, 0, 0, 2` you'd want to return `size5`?  And if it was `1, 0, 1, 0, 2`...then what?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return the column header from the column that has a non-zero number, you can use this in `G2`, and drag down:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B2:$F2<>0)*(COLUMN($B2:$F2))))-COLUMN($B$1)+1)
```

[image]

Note you can wrap that in `IFERROR([formula], "")` to hide the error that occurs if there's not a cell that's not equal to `0`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. So that code, when I drag it down, will work out the median size of plant for that row. But what does it do when, for example, it has 2 size1 plants and 2 size2 plants in the same row? It can't have an intermediate median between two categories can it?

Comment: @Harry.Drew - Can you update your OP with more detail? It looked like there's only going to be one column with a non-zero number, but I suppose that's not the case?  If, say row `2` had `2` under `Size1`, and `2` under `Size2`, what do you expect to show in the return column G?

Comment: Okay I think I've done that. Sorry the first example wasn't clear!